# Angular routerlink open in modal instead of new page

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build a table which will have a lot of data, some of these data I would like to display in a modal after I click on a specific row. 
I created a component modal which was supposed to display more data, but the problem is when I click on a specific row it takes me to another page, I would like to display that as a modal, not in new page.

Here is my html

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of listOfUsers" routerLink="/sidebarComp">
                   <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
                   <td>{{data.ID}}</td> ...
```

Here is my routing.module.js
  `{ path: 'sidebarComp', component: SidebarComponent }`

Does anyone know how to display new component but not redirect to a new page?

Comment: write a click event on the tr and open dialog while capturing the event.

Answer (score 0):

you should use modal such as ngx-bootstrap modal

[ngx-bootstrap Modal](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)

or user angular material dialog

[angular material dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

to show your component in entry component outside DOM